# Как сделать отнимание score (очков) при условии и как делать проверку?

Tags: xcode, spritekit

Как сделать проверку объектов в *SpriteKit* для подсчета *score*;

```
for (SKNode * drug1 in [self.droppingdrug1 copy ]){
    if (CGRectContainsRect(self.car.frame, drug1.frame)){
       [drug1 removeFromParent];
         self.score++;
        [self.droppingdrug1 removeObject:drug1];
```

Прибавка очков идёт, а как сделать, чтобы если машина не словила - очки отнимало?

Answer (score 1):

Придумать какое-то условие, при котором объект считается упущенным, например, когда он покидает экран, убирать его из массива объектов и отнимать очки.

```
if (CGRectContainsRect(self.car.frame, drug1.frame)){
    [drug1 removeFromParent];
    self.score++;
    [self.droppingdrug1 removeObject:drug1];
} else  if !(CGRectContainsRect(self.gameArea.frame, drug1.frame)) {
    [drug1 removeFromParent];
    self.score--;
    [self.droppingdrug1 removeObject:drug1];
}
```